# Regex extract text between pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

i need your help with a regex in javascript.

I've got an a-tag with follow pattern

```
<a href='#'>
  <!--:de-->some german text<!--:--><!--:en-->some english text<!--:-->
</a>
```

So, now i'm searching for a regular expression what extract me each part

```
 1. <!--:de-->some german text<!--:-->
 2. <!--:en-->some german text<!--:-->
```

Thanks VERY much in advance

Comment: Are you actually asking for a regular expression that can tell the difference between English text and German text? Seriously?

Comment: Do you have any kind of separator between the german text and the english text?

Comment: nooo sorry i forget to make the code tags visible :)

Comment: Oh good - that definitely moves this out of the realm of the imagination :-)

Comment: This comments exchange was absolute gold

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = '<!--:de-->some german text<!--:--><!--:en-->some english text<!--:-->'; 
var match =  str.match(/de-->([^<]+).+?en[^>]+>([^<]+)/i);
var textInDe = match[1]; 
var textInEn = match[2];
```

Comment: … is it possible to check with an if statement or something if the defined regex is available?

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe: try if(match != null) { .. }

Answer (score 2):

Try this Javascript code:

```
var ger = /<!--:de-->.*?<!--:-->/g;
document.writeln(html.match(ger).map(function (s) { return s; }));

var eng = /<!--:en-->.*?<!--:-->/g;
document.writeln(html.match(eng).map(function (s) { return s; }));
```

#### OUTPUT

some german text

some english text

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting more than 2 parts, i would recommend you split the string by the delimiter

```
var str="<!--:de-->some german text<!--:--><!--:en-->some english text<!--:--><!--:fr-->some french text<!--:-->";

var col_array=str.split("<!--:-->");
var part_num=0;
while (part_num < col_array.length)
{
 document.write(col_array[part_num]+"<br>");
 part_num+=1;
}
```